# What is a system of generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I was reading a paper called "Numerical semigroups and applications" and came across the following proposition. If $S$ is a numerical semigroup, then the proposition states *Every numerical semigroup is finitely generated*. The first line of the proof: Let $A$ be a system of generators of $S$ ($S$ itself is a system of generators).

My question is what is a *system* of generators? If $A$ was just a set of generators of $S$, then I understand, but the author uses the word *system*. What's the distinction here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would read *system* as synonymous with *set* in this context. The generators form a "system" in the sense that you can then express every element in terms of them, so you're working within that "system".

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks!